# For the Paragraph without header part images are not coming

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm having the two header files (h1, h2), I had write the image information using the below XSL:

My Input XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="Body">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="h1">
           <xsl:if test="not(self::p/img)">
             <xsl:variable name="image" select="preceding-sibling::*[1][self::p/img]" />
             <topic>
                <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2"/></xsl:attribute>
                <title>
                   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                </title>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h2">
                   <xsl:choose>
                      <xsl:when test="self::h2">
                         <topic>
                            <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2"/></xsl:attribute>
                            <title>
                               <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                            </title>
                            <body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[not(self::p/img)] except ."/></body>
                         </topic>
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:otherwise>
                         <body><xsl:apply-templates select="$image|current-group()[not(self::p/img)]"/></body>
                      </xsl:otherwise>
                   </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
                </topic>
             </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
       </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="p">
       <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
       </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="img">
      <xsl:element name="image">
            <xsl:if test="@src">
               <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@src"/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
       </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
```

My first input XML is(the image is not coming for this type):

```
<Body>
<p><img src="https://tneb.com"/></p>
<h1>Taking</h1>
<h2>Blood Pressure?</h2>
<p>second.</p>
</Body>
```

My second XML file:(Its generating image correctly)

```
<Body>
<p><img src="https://tneb.com"/></p>
<h1>Taking</h1>
<p>first</p>
<h2>Blood Pressure?</h2>
<p>second.</p>
</Body>
```

Generated output for first XML:

```
<topic id="topic_1">
   <title>Taking</title>
   <topic id="topic_2">
      <title>Blood Pressure?</title>
      <body>
         <p>second.</p>
      </body>
   </topic>
</topic>
```

Expected output would be:

```
<topic id="topic_1">
   <title>Taking</title>
<body>
  <p>
     <image href="https://tneb.com"/>
  </p>
</body>
   <topic id="topic_2">
      <title>Blood Pressure?</title>
      <body>
         <p>second.</p>
      </body>
   </topic>
</topic>
```

I have to create XSL for both type of inputs, Whether it having paragraph or not with the  tag. Please suggest the coding for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add some logic to the check of `self:h2` so that if it occurs in the first position (i.e. it has not `p` tags before it), then output the image there first

```
<xsl:when test="self::h2">
   <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <body><xsl:apply-templates select="$image"/></body>
   </xsl:if>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Body">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="h1">
           <xsl:if test="not(self::p/img)">
             <xsl:variable name="image" select="preceding-sibling::*[1][self::p/img]" />
             <topic>
                <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2"/></xsl:attribute>
                <title>
                   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                </title>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h2">
                   <xsl:choose>
                      <xsl:when test="self::h2">
                        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                            <body><xsl:apply-templates select="$image"/></body>
                        </xsl:if>
                         <topic>
                            <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2"/></xsl:attribute>
                            <title>
                               <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                            </title>
                            <body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[not(self::p/img)] except ."/></body>
                         </topic>
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:otherwise>
                         <body><xsl:apply-templates select="$image|current-group()[not(self::p/img)]"/></body>
                      </xsl:otherwise>
                   </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
                </topic>
             </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
       </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="p">
       <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
       </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="img">
      <xsl:element name="image">
            <xsl:if test="@src">
               <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@src"/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
       </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi @Timc. Please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762246/the-header-image-needs-to-come-in-between-the-body